# Does TFS 2010 lock a project collection when it's being cloned?

Tags: team-foundation-server

We're planning to migrate a project collection currently hosted on TFS 2010 to TFS 2012. We want to keep the current installation running while resolving any issues that might arise, so we need to copy the current project collection to the new server.

However, TFS doesn't allow us to attach a restored database backup directly. The database first must be detached from the original TFS installation. We can get around that limitation by cloning the project collection and detaching the clone, but we're not sure whether that would also impact the original project collection.

Does TFS lock the original project collection while it's being cloned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by 'cloning a project collection'?

You have a couple options here:

1. Detach your collection from TFS2010, backup the database, reattach the collection to TFS2010, restore your database backup and attach it to your TFS2012 system.  This involves some short downtime on your TFS2010 system.
2. Backup your entire TFS2010 database set.  Restore them to a another (temporary) sytem.  Run 'tfsconfig changeserverid' to restamp the databases.  Run the TFS 2012 Upgrade wizard to upgrade the databases to TFS 2012 (or Run the TFS 2010 AT-Only wizard to keep them at TFS2010)  Detach the collection and Attach it to your TFS2012 system.

Will

Comment: When you attach the database, you can include the /clone flag to change the single project collection's ID. I thought that option cloned the actual project collection database instead of just changing the ID. It seems that the first option is the best solution to my problem.